# Clicking on links in PDF in JxBrowser results in errors

Tags: jxbrowser

I am using JxBrowser 6.14.2 in a Java Swing application and I'm encountering an issue when loading a PDF and attempting to load content for any links in the PDF document.

It seems to be related to the tab handling code in the Chrome PDF extension and it happens when using the JxBrowser default `PopupHandler` as well as a custom one.

Get the following error when the PDF is loaded:

```
[0104/095806:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.get: No tab with id: 5.
    at promises.push.Promise.then.streamInfo.tabUrl (chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/browser_api.js:159:21)
    at chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/browser_api.js:158:21", source: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/index.html (0)
```

Then, when clicking any URL or `mailto` link, the following error occurs:

```
[0104/095952:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.update: No current window
    at NavigatorDelegate.navigateInCurrentTab (chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/navigator.js:42:19)
    at Navigator.onViewportReceived_ (chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/navigator.js:169:31)
    at OpenPDFParamsParser.getViewportFromUrlParams (chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/open_pdf_params_parser.js:131:7)
    at Navigator.navigate (chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/navigator.js:125:28)
    at PDFViewer.handlePluginMessage_ (chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/pdf.js:614:27)", source: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/index.html (0)
```

The same errors even occur if a popup handler that "disables" popups is installed:

```
browser.setPopupHandler(p -> {
    browser.loadURL(p.getURL());
    return null;
});
```

Any ideas on how I might resolve this issue so that links in PDF documents behave as expected?

Comment: An updated build with the fix is available for download from https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/eap/jxbrowser-6.18.1-b10-eap-cross-desktop-win_mac_linux.zip

Answer (score 0):

My name is Dmitry and I’m on the JxBrowser Support team.

Thank you for reporting that issue.

Currently, links from PDF do not work in JxBrowser. I have created an appropriate task in our issue tracking system and we will fix it in one of the future versions of JxBrowser.